# Using SQL DENSE_RANK to determine duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, rank, dense-rank

Here is an example of the data for which I am trying to find all the orders with same quantities, ignoring the OrderID column

```
Product     Location      Customer    OrderID    Quantity
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2011        10
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2012        10
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2013        15
```

So, I used DENSE_RANK function in the SQL

```
Select Product,Location,Customer,OrderID,Quantity,
Ranking = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Product,Location,Customer,Quantity
ORDER BY OrderID ASC)
FROM MyTable
```

to get the data below

```
Product     Location      Customer    OrderID    Quantity Ranking
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2011        10       1
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2012        10       2
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2013        15       1
```

So, based on the ranking I was able to filter out the records that have the same quantity across different orderIDs and treat them as one.
So far everything is good and I am happy. But, one of another crazy requirement is this form of aggregation should be done only for the first change in quantity. For example, if the above data happens to be like one below

```
Product     Location      Customer    OrderID    Quantity
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2011        10
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2012        10
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2013        15
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2014        15
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2015        15
```

The same SQL would produce result

```
Product     Location      Customer    OrderID    Quantity Ranking
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2011        10       1
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2012        10       2
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2013        15       1
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2013        15       2
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2013        15       3
```

But, I would need the result to be

```
Product     Location      Customer    OrderID    Quantity Ranking
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2011        10       1
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2012        10       2
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2013        15       1
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2013        15       1
 Eggs        Chicago        XYZ        2013        15       1
```

Please, note the ranking remains 1 for all the records after the first change in quantity.

Is it possible to tweak my SQL to get the above behavior?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What about using ROW_NUMBER instead of DENSE_RANK?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER(), RANK() all gives the same behavior

Comment: Should the OrderID really be 2013 for each of the last three rows in your desired data? Even though they are 2013, 2014, 2015 in your sample data

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use `DENSE_RANK()` to eliminate duplicate rows in your data.

It seems you’ve already solved your problem. If you want to eliminate the duplicates, use the same SQL code you have above and delete any rows with `Ranking > 1`. This will leave you with one copy of each row with the same unique key (e.g. `Product`, `Location`, `Customer`, `OrderID`).

Answer (score 1):

This feels a bit dirty but I think it's correct:

```
SELECT
  Product,
  Location,
  Customer,
  OrderID,
  Quantity,
  DENSE_RANK() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY 
            Product,
            Location,
            Customer,
            Quantity
          ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN 
              Quantity = (SELECT MIN(Quantity) FROM Orders) THEN OrderID 
            ELSE 0 END  ASC
         ) AS Ranking
FROM 
  Orders
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca800/17)